# Task :react-native-location:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED while building apk

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build my apk & I'm getting this error while building my release apk in react native. Is there any way to fix this react-native-location error?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue while building my apk in react native. To solve this issue you need to:

```
1- cd android and then ./gradlew clean
2- then in your root directory run yarn jetify or npx jetify
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project, with React Native 0.71.0, I got this error due to package android.support.annotation. So I followed the instructions provided [here](https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location/issues/212) and added a patch (trough patch-package) to update the react-native-location source code. So here is the final result, under `patches/react-native-location+2.5.0.patch`

```
index 6dbdd3b..1a4de95 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-location/android/src/main/java/com/github/reactnativecommunity/location/RNPlayServicesLocationProvider.java
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-location/android/src/main/java/com/github/reactnativecommunity/location/RNPlayServicesLocationProvider.java
@@ -6,8 +6,9 @@ import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.IntentSender;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.location.Location;
-import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
-import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
+
+import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
+import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
 
 import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
 import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-location/android/src/main/java/com/github/reactnativecommunity/location/Utils.java b/node_modules/react-native-location/android/src/main/java/com/github/reactnativecommunity/location/Utils.java
index 6059fdc..b66dd63 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-location/android/src/main/java/com/github/reactnativecommunity/location/Utils.java
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-location/android/src/main/java/com/github/reactnativecommunity/location/Utils.java
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@ package com.github.reactnativecommunity.location;
 
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.os.Build;
-import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
+import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
 
 import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
 import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
```